# Symfony 1.4 pagination with filtering not working

Tags: filter, pagination, symfony-1.4

I have a Symfony 1.4 project with simple CRUD modules.  For a couple of the modules, I want the ability to filter the results on the index page on one or more fields.  I followed the method described [here](http://www.michelsalib.com/2010/10/how-to-use-filters-on-custom-fields/) for filtering and pagination. Essentially, the values entered via the filters restrict the query given to the pager object.  This appears to work, but only for the first page.  If I try to navigate to any subsequent pages, it shows me rows from the unfiltered list.

The links at the bottom of each page are coded as:

```
link_to($page, 'appliance/index?page='.$page, 'class ="pager"')
```

I assumed that the query used by the pager would remain the same, but it appears that fetching another page from the pager object resets it with the default query.

Any ideas as to how to correct this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. get applied filters by using `$sf_request->getParameter('your_filter_array');` or use your form object `getValues()` method
2. merge the array with `compact('page')`
3. generate a query string out of it with `http_build_query()`
4. append it to your link.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll give that a try and let you know how I get on